# Thread-safe queue for Logger thread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

So, I have a MMO game server listening for connections (up to 1100, hardcoded limit because of game design) and needing to log everything without blocking my main thread (which handles all the virtual-world logic), including but not limited to: what NPCs give to players, when a monster/player dies, every single chat message, when players level up, when players drop an item to the ground, etc.

I get a thread from a pool for each connection, and each thread can log to a file at any time (it may actually never happen, but the server must be prepared enough to handle it appropriately).

I thought about an independent logging thread constantly checking an order queue, until it is not empty.

```
while Game is Running
    Check the queue, if it's empty, sleep.
    File IO. Open plain-text file, log and gracefully close it.
    Repeat.
```

Is a linked list enough for organizing the queue and just protect it with a mutex like this?

```
LogThreadOrder Queue[1024];

LogThreadOrder *FirstThreadOrder;
int NumberOfOrders;

struct LogThreadOrder {
    char FileName[4096];
    char LogMessage[4096];
    LogThreadOrder* NextOrder;
};

void Log(const char* FileName, const char* LogMessage) {
    LogMutex.lock();

    ProtocolThreadOrder* Order = Queue[NumberOfOrders++];
    Order->NextOrder = FirstThreadOrder;
    FirstThreadOrder = Order;

    LogMutex.release();

}


int LogThreadLoop() {
    // Loop through Queue until its empty.
}
```

So, my question is:

- Is this a smart design?
- Is it thread-safe?
- Is there any better way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do?
- Would it be better/more-efficient to have multiple logger threads and multiple queues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pseudocode could be made to work, but it's difficult in C and mutex synchronization is inefficient. In my experience it's always better to use existing, well-established, asynchronous [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanisms between threads like [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe). Even then there are many pitfalls and when dependencies aren't a problem using something like ZeroMQ might be the best idea. Specifically something like [this](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Signaling-Between-Threads-PAIR-Sockets). I don't think having multiple threads is a good idea, as file you want to write to will be a contention point.